# onProgressUpdate done at the end of the AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, publish, async-onprogressupdate

```
public class VisitTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
private UserSocket userSocket;
private TextView visitView;
private Context context;
```

Starting AsyncTask

```
public VisitTask(UserSocket userSocket, TextView visitView, Context context) {
    this.userSocket = userSocket;
    this.visitView = visitView;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    visitView.setText(null);
}
```

doInBackgroud... visiting the rooms in the graph

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ClientSocket clientSocket = userSocket.getcSocket();
    Integer i = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!isCancelled()) {

        try {
            publishProgress(i);
            rooms = clientSocket.visitGraph(i);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i = rooms.get((int) (rooms.size() * Math.random()));

        if (i == 16) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return clientSocket.close();
}
```

trying to update the textview in real time with the number of the visited room.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    //Integer currentRoom = values[0];
        /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.s1));*/
    // TextView visitView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VisitView);
visitView.append(String.format("You're visiting " + values[0] + " " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())) + '\n');
}
```

}

Unexpectedly onProgressUpdate method is called once for all at the end of the AsyncTask.
Could anyone help me please?
I call it here after logging with socket connection.

```
MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(ip, args);
    myClientTask.execute();
    UserSocket userSocket = myClientTask.get();
    if (userSocket.getBoolean()) {
        new Toast(getApplicationContext()).makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        VisitTask visitTask = new VisitTask(userSocket, visitView, getApplicationContext());
        visitTask.execute();
        if (visitTask.get()) {
            new Toast(getApplicationContext()).makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've completed your visit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling it in your code??

Comment: Is the list of rooms not always 16?

Comment: No, 16 is the id of the exit room. I'm choosing a random number from the possible alternatives.